# What does this vector push_back statement mean?

Tags: c++, vector

Waht does the following mean?

```
vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> Graph;
Graph.push_back(vector<pair<int, int>>()); // What does this statement mean?
```

I was just wondering because the statement didn't have any values. I can now see from the rest of the code I was browsing that the initialized locations are being referenced later in the code. That's pretty much what I thought, but I was not sure. Sorry if it was a newbie question, but I'm new to vectors. Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Could you clarify your question - what exactly are you interested in? Stackoverflow is not a language reference site.

Comment: It means: you didnt even use 5 seconds to read any docs

Comment: I pretty much thought I knew the answer but wasn't sure. The language references I saw on the web didn't say anything about the ">>" operator.

Comment: This is not `>>` operator. It is template closing brackets.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I've done most of my coding with arrays, so I hadn't seen that before. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It "adds" a newly initialized `vector<pair<int,int>>` to the "back" of the vector with the name `Graph` (i.e. *after* the last entry, if any).

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering because the statement didn't have any values. I can now see from the rest of the code I was browsing that the initialized locations are being referenced later in the code. That's pretty much what I thought, but I was not  sure. Thanks for the reply. Sorry if it was a newbie question, but I'm new to vectors.

Comment: I din't think the question deserves the downvotes. You understood the push_back, just not what the argument meant in this case.